# Error con el nombre de la tabla en JPA, Hibernate, MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Tengo una clase que se corresponde a una tabla de una base de datos

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TCliente")
public class Cliente implements Serializable
```

Creo un registro desde código sin problema, luego hago una consulta

```
EntityManager manager = emf.createEntityManager();
List<Cliente> clientes = (List<Cliente>) manager.createQuery("FROM TCliente").getResultList();
```

y recibo el siguiente error:

```
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: TCliente is not mapped [FROM TCliente]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:740)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at com.jpadomain.test.TestClientes.imprimirTodos(TestClientes.java:68)
    at com.jpadomain.test.TestClientes.main(TestClientes.java:33)
```

pero si cambio el nombre de la tabla "TCliente" y la llamo "Cliente", teniendo su tabla "Cliente" correspondiente en la BD ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Cliente")
public class Cliente implements Serializable
```

la consulta funciona perfectamente

```
EntityManager manager = emf.createEntityManager();
List<Cliente> clientes = (List<Cliente>) manager.createQuery("FROM Cliente").getResultList();
```

Tan sólo con cambiar "TCliente" por "Cliente" ya no me da error siendo ambas tablas idénticas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate, es un framework para el manejo de base de datos orientado a objetos. Con lo cual, las consultas están relacionadas con Clases. Salvo que hagas consultas con nativequery, el resto se refiere a clases. Tu from en la consulta tiene que ser Cliente al igual que tu clase.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo he entendido, pensaba que era por el tema de las mayúsculas/minúsculas.